# Readout counter

Tags: python, selenium

I want to readout the following counter with selenium: It is located on a homepage in a table:

```
<td>
<div style="....">
<font id="counter0">1:27:31</font
</div>
```

I tried to readout the counter by and try to save it in variable to print it out

```
driver.find_element_by_id(id_='counter0')'
```

I always get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="counter0"]
```

may someone has an idea to get the value to use it in futher calculations? Thanks

Comment: print(driver.find_element_by_id('counter0').text) Simply do the following.

Comment: If the closing tag really missing a gt sign (you have `</font`)?  Or was that a typo in your post?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan: Thank you for your quick response. It is working fine :) also thanks to you Tim Roberts: Its just a typo